# How do I count the number of occurance of '_' in my file name using Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to count the number of time '_' (under score) is appearing in my file name. How do I do that?

Comment: This is to be done using UNIX shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $filename | tr -c -d _ | wc -c
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use tr.

```
$ echo "8979858774_/hkjhjkh_kjh.hjghjg/_jhkj/_/" | tr -d _ -c | wc -c
   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```
echo "$filename" | grep -o _ | wc -l
```

Or for shells that support this, such as Bash, ksh and zsh:

```
u=${filename//_}
echo $((${#filename} - ${#u}))
```

Answer (score -2):

Probably not the most elegant or perfect solution, but should do the trick:

```
echo $filename|split -C 1 - /tmp/foobar
grep -l '_' /tmp/foobar* |wc -l
rm /tmp/foobar*
```

Comment: I still need to try this out... Thanks for the help Kimvais